# Github Script can't use outputs

Tags: github, github-actions, github-script

I am trying to create a PR message as a result of a failed action but the message's body is always erroring out as being "blank".
This is the code I'm running on my action, all those console.logs are empty and I can't understand why.

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: Could you share your repository (if it is public) to reproduce the error?

Comment: Please don't show screenshots, but paste your code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question